# Loop through PHP file_get_contents and do a put request

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, webhooks

Im trying to loop through a json which I get from an url using `file_get_contents("someurl")`.
I also pass an ID to that url which i get from a parsed webhook.

The problem comes with the for/foreach, i can't seem to loop through `$data` when it has more than one `'producto'`

Before the loop continues I have to send the data taken from `$stock` and `$precio` through `$stock_quantity` and `$price` to the product url defined by `$sku` taken from the json by `$codigo_var`

Any idea on how I could send those variables no matter if i get only one `'producto'` or multiple `'producto'`?

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$products = json_decode($data, true);
$id = ($products['recurso_id']);
$dato = file_get_contents("www.something.com/$id");


$decodata = json_decode($dato, true);

foreach($decodata as $data){
        $sku = $data['producto']['codigo_var'];
        $stock_quantity= $data['producto']['stock'];
        $price = $data['producto']['precios'][0]['precio'];

        print_r($woocommerce->put('products/$sku', $stock_quantity));
        print_r($woocommerce->put('products/$sku', $price));
}
```

JSON example:

```
{"total":"3","offset":0,"limit":100,"repos":"https:\/\/www.apliton.com\/repos\/hogarytecno","productos":[{"id":"2438","estado":"1","fecha_alta":"2021-02-04 14:10:09","fecha_modif":"2021-04-19 10:42:58","codigo":"PE-BM110","codigo_var":"PE-BM110RS","nombre":"BATIDORA PEABODY DE MESA PE-BM110RS 1000 WATTS ROSA","tipo_id":"1","novedad":"0","detacado_pzdo_id":"0","web_mdp_destac":"1","web_mdp_bonif":"1","med_ancho":"41.00","med_alto":"30.50","med_largo":"37.50","peso_kg":"6.27","rubro_id":null,"rubro_nombre":"","rubro_subid":null,"marca_id":"7","marca_nombre":"PEABODY","iva_ptaje":"21.00","imp_int_ptaje":null,"club":"0","club_puntos_canje":"0","club_puntos_cred":"0","web_club_publica_canje":"0","stock":"23.00","envio_me":"1","envio_me_gratis":false,"envio_me_gratis_valor":"0","ml_link":"","colores":[],"tipo_medidas":{"id":null,"nombre":""},"medidas":{"id":null,"nombre":""},"precios":[{"id":"3","nombre":"E-COMMERCE","tipo_moneda_id":"1","precio":"14859.5042","bonif":"0.00","precio_venc":"0.0000"}],"fotos":null},{"id":"2378","estado":"1","fecha_alta":"2021-01-09 09:30:40","fecha_modif":"2021-04-19 10:40:54","codigo":"PE-BM110","codigo_var":"PE-BM110L","nombre":"BATIDORA PEABODY DE MESA PE-BM110L 1000 WATTS MARFIL","tipo_id":"1","novedad":"0","detacado_pzdo_id":"0","web_mdp_destac":"1","web_mdp_bonif":"1","med_ancho":"41.00","med_alto":"30.50","med_largo":"37.50","peso_kg":"6.27","rubro_id":null,"rubro_nombre":"","rubro_subid":null,"marca_id":"7","marca_nombre":"PEABODY","iva_ptaje":"21.00","imp_int_ptaje":null,"club":"0","club_puntos_canje":"0","club_puntos_cred":"0","web_club_publica_canje":"0","stock":"333.00","envio_me":"1","envio_me_gratis":false,"envio_me_gratis_valor":"0","ml_link":"","colores":[],"tipo_medidas":{"id":null,"nombre":""},"medidas":{"id":null,"nombre":""},"precios":[{"id":"3","nombre":"E-COMMERCE","tipo_moneda_id":"1","precio":"14859.5042","bonif":"0.00","precio_venc":"0.0000"}],"fotos":null},{"id":"2377","estado":"1","fecha_alta":"2021-01-07 08:51:21","fecha_modif":"2021-04-19 10:40:56","codigo":"PE-BM110","codigo_var":"PE-BM110R","nombre":"BATIDORA PEABODY DE MESA PE-BM110 1000W ROJA","tipo_id":"1","novedad":"0","detacado_pzdo_id":"0","web_mdp_destac":"1","web_mdp_bonif":"1","med_ancho":"41.00","med_alto":"30.50","med_largo":"37.50","peso_kg":"6.27","rubro_id":null,"rubro_nombre":"","rubro_subid":null,"marca_id":"7","marca_nombre":"PEABODY","iva_ptaje":"21.00","imp_int_ptaje":null,"club":"0","club_puntos_canje":"0","club_puntos_cred":"0","web_club_publica_canje":"0","stock":"68.00","envio_me":"1","envio_me_gratis":false,"envio_me_gratis_valor":"0","ml_link":"","colores":[],"tipo_medidas":{"id":null,"nombre":""},"medidas":{"id":null,"nombre":""},"precios":[{"id":"3","nombre":"E-COMMERCE","tipo_moneda_id":"1","precio":"14859.5042","bonif":"0.00","precio_venc":"0.0000"}],"fotos":null}]}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON.

Comment: Sure! I added it

Comment: I think you need to change the `foreach` to `foreach($decodata['producto'] as $data){` and then remove that index from inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
<?php
$arr = json_decode($json, true); // turn json into an associative array

foreach($arr['productos'] as $producto) {
    $sku = $producto['codigo_var'];
    $stock_quantity= $producto['stock'];
    $price = $producto['precios'][0]['precio'];
    
    // ... etc.
}
```

You can use `print_r($arr)` or `var_dump($arr)` to help you visualize the array structure, and reference the data items you need.

[demo](https://3v4l.org/3p9cX)